# JavaFX Scene resize

Tags: javafx, tabs, autoresize

I'm looking for a solution to change JFX Scene height and width.

I have Scene which holds AnchorPane which holds TabPane which holds tabs.

Tabs are created dynamically and they hold different size AnchorPanes.
When new tab is created i want to:

1. TabPane adjust it's height and width to new tab (with focus on it) AnchorPane
2. Scene AnchorPane adjust it's height and width to new TabPane size.
3. Scene adjust it's height and width to new Scene AnchorPane size.

I can't find or think of any solution. How to solve this problem?

BR

Answer (score 0):

do you want to do it when a new tab is created, or when you switch tabs? If it's when you switch tabs, you can use `setOnSelectionChanged` on each tab to define the appropriate resizing behavior of its Scene and AnchorPane.

Comment: I want to do this on both events - creation and change.